# Data binding in container user control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have user control that behaves as container:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GUI.Views.Components.Messages.WindowFrame"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="windowFrame">
   <Grid>        
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=windowFrame,Path=InsideContent}">
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and here is the code behind:

```
public partial class WindowFrame : UserControl
{
    public WindowFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public object InsideContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(InsideContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InsideContentProperty, value); }
    }



    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for InsideContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InsideContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("InsideContent", typeof(object), typeof(WindowFrame), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

everything works great untill I try to have data binding in the future "InsideContent":

```
           <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:GUI.ViewModels.Converters"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI.Views.Components.Messages" x:Class="GUI.Views.Components.Messages.SimpleMessageBox"
    Title="SimpleMessageBox" Height="202" Width="438"
     x:Name="simpleMB" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:MessageTypeToMessageBoxPictureConverter x:Key="MessageTypeToMessageBoxPictureConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <local:WindowFrame WindowTitle="{Binding ElementName=simpleMB,Path=MessageBoxTitle}">
        <local:WindowFrame.InsideContent>
            <Grid>
                <!-- Data binding here fails! -->
                <Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding ElementName=simpleMB,Path=MessageType,Converter={StaticResource MessageTypeToMessageBoxPictureConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="20,10,0,111" Text="{Binding ElementName=simpleMB,Path=MessageBoxMessage}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <!---->
                </Grid>
            </local:WindowFrame.InsideContent>
        </local:WindowFrame>

         <!-- Data binding here works! -->
                <TextBlock Margin="10,138,10,48" Text="{Binding ElementName=simpleMB,Path=MessageBoxMessage}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <Image  Stretch="None" Source="{Binding ElementName=simpleMB,Path=MessageType,Converter={StaticResource MessageTypeToMessageBoxPictureConverter}}" Margin="42,30,199,39"/>
            </Grid>
```

It's like that in the "InsideContent" (the grid), the "simpleMB" user control is not known any more).

How can I fix that and why is it happen?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
 <ContentControl  Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=InsideContent}" />

<local:WindowFrame WindowTitle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=MessageBoxTitle}">

 <Image Stretch="None" Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=MessageType,Converter={StaticResource MessageTypeToMessageBoxPictureConverter}}"/>

 <TextBlock Margin="20,10,0,111" Height="30"  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=MessageBoxMessage}" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

I think the elementName is not working because local:WindowFrame.InsideContent is not UIElement and hence it cannot find as the ElementName search logic goes by searching for controls up and down in Tree

Comment: I will try it and update.
Anyway, the part of the "WindowTitle" (another DP) works, I guess because it's not in the nested control.
I think that nested control like my example, doesn't know about the existence of the "simpleMB" because it had created antoher scope.

Thank you in the meanwhile!